# python add items to list and stop when you get an empty value

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I have an excel document that I am reading, it has an unknown number of lines, I want to add each line and the three values of columns A B and C into a list and then stop once I reach none. I then want to run an action on each item in the list.

I am terrible with `if/for loops` if someone could help.

Below is loading argument 3 as the workbook and sheet. I need to start at line `A61` and add `A61,B61,C61` to a list and keep going until A whatever is = to none.

Alright so I got this far, now how do I run a command for each item in the row?

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(sys.argv[3])
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
first_kvm_ip = str(sheet.cell_value(34,1))
last_kvm_ip = str(sheet.cell_value(35,1))
kvm_netmask = str(sheet.cell_value(36,1))
rows = sheet.nrows
curr_row = 52
while (curr_row < rows - 1):
    curr_row += 1
    row1 = int(sheet.cell_value(curr_row,0))
    row2 = str(sheet.cell_value(curr_row,1))
    vlanls1.append(row1)
    vlanls2.append(row2)
```

I want to run a command for each item in row1
vlan create(row1,row2)

I assume I need a for i iteration. I just need help with that.

I need to run this command for each iteration of row1 and row2

```
mo = FabricVlan(parent_mo_or_dn="fabric/lan", sharing="none", name=row2,         id=row1, mcast_policy_name="", policy_owner="local", default_net="no",     pub_nw_name="", compression_type="included")
handle.add_mo(mo)
```

Alright I think I finally got it. Thanks for the help guys.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(sys.argv[3])
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
first_kvm_ip = str(sheet.cell_value(34,1))
last_kvm_ip = str(sheet.cell_value(35,1))
kvm_netmask = str(sheet.cell_value(36,1))
rows = sheet.nrows
curr_row = 52
while (curr_row < rows - 1):
    curr_row += 1
    row1 = int(sheet.cell_value(curr_row,0))
    row2 = str(sheet.cell_value(curr_row,1))
    vlanls1.append(row1)
    vlanls2.append(row2)
for x,y in zip(vlanls1,vlanls2):
    mo = FabricVlan(parent_mo_or_dn="fabric/lan", sharing="none", name=y,   id=x, mcast_policy_name="", policy_owner="local", default_net="no",       pub_nw_name="", compression_type="included")
    handle.add_mo(mo)
```

Comment: What all have you tried till now? Have you tried looking up similar problems of reading excel files on google or stackoverflow??

Comment: Absolutely, been looking for about 3-4 hours before giving up. Its not reading the excel file that I really need help with, its adding the data to a list and executing the amount of items on the list and then stopping.

Answer (score 1):

`worksheet.rows` returns a list of all rows, no matter how many there are. Each row in that list is itself a list of the cells in that row. Knowing this, it would be fairly easy to implement a `for` loop that iterates through each row and appends the first three cells to a new list.

This code should do the trick.

```
myList = []
for row in sheet.rows:
    myList.append([row[0],row[1],row[2]])
```

I do recommend going through the openpyxl documentation though, it will avoid you some trouble to come. Also, read up on the way that for loops work if you know you have trouble with them :)

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm

Comment: Can you post that at the end of your original post instead? I can't tell what's going on in this cramped space haha